# How do I remove the .html from the end of URL while using SiteGround

Tags: html, reactjs, .htaccess, url, nav

I had originally built my website in React before learning that my client is using SiteGround so I had to change everything over to a basic HTML format. I have my navbar using href = "fileName.html" to navigate the page. This leads the URL to become www."siteName".com/"fileName.html" once navigating off the homepage.

This is what I have so far in my .htaccess to remove the .html from the end:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[^./]+)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule (.*) $1.html [L]

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
  RewriteRule . /index.html [L]

</IfModule>
```

This does not seem to be working. Should I change my .htaccess file? Should I change the way my navbar navigates the pages?

Comment: Welcome to SO, thanks for sharing your code. So you want to redirect url from `http://localhost:80/file.html` to `http://localhost:80/file`? I mean are you hitting `http://localhost:80/file.html` link in browser? Kindly confirm once.

Answer (score 0):

With your shown samples/attempts, please try following .htaccess Rules file. Please make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
Options -MultiViews
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteBase /

###Rules for handling .html to without html uri in browser.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \s/([^.]*)\.html\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.html -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ $1.html [L]

##Rule from OP's already existing .htaccess file.
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L,NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: @Carlos Benitez, could you please do let me know if above solution has worked for you?